# Online payments fraud prevention best practices

Tags: paypal, payment, credit-card

I'm after some reliable approach or algorithm that helps detect suspicious activity in online payments with credit cards. For instance, if someone makes very frequent payment requests or payment amount is beyond certain limit and so on. In theory, it's possible that payments from given user come very fast.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your payment processing/gateway service provider will either have some built-in service and/or recommendations. [Otherwise and/or supplement](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=credit+card+anti+fraud+services)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [PayPal Fraud Management Filters](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/fmf/integration-guide/FMFIntro/).